# check_rhub(): Preparing build, see status at

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran

I'm trying to use `devtools::check_rhub` before upload package to CRAN.

However, seems like the following code (**Preparing build, see status at**) runs forever.

Should I keep waiting for this? Or is there any other thing I need to do?

```
devtools::check_rhub()
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\package/DESCRIPTION' (612ms)
-  preparing 'package':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  installing the package to build vignettes
√  creating vignettes (14s)
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'package_0.2.0.tar.gz'
   
-  Uploading package
-  Preparing build, see status at
   https://builder.r-hub.io/status/package_0.2.0.tar.gz-78930a5c07
   https://builder.r-hub.io/status/package_0.2.0.tar.gz-f51c23a0e0
   https://builder.r-hub.io/status/package_0.2.0.tar.gz-b1efba0d90
```

Comment: What does "forever" mean to you? Have you checked the provided URLs?

Comment: Around half day keep running? Still waiting. The provide URLs doesn't shown anything. Just a blank message with ```Status: ...
Duration: ...```

Comment: Then something went wrong. Might be an issue on your side or with the server/service. As a first step, I'd try using the rhub package directly (or even their [web interface](https://builder.r-hub.io/)) instead of going through devtools. (I'm assuming your package passes all checks in reasonable time if you do it locally.)

Comment: I tried use ```check_rhub()``` directly. But the error said ```Error in check_rhub() : could not find function "check_rhub"``` And that's why I use devtool:: in front

Comment: Or should I use  ```rhub::check()``` instead?

Comment: Yes ............